# Navigation menu not working for the new cms pages added?

Tags: magento-2.1, menu, cms-pages

Website is already been done right now while I am adding new cms page and linking it to menu it is working fine in desktop when I open it in mobile and when I open that new page then navigation bar is not working for rest of the pages which are already been done for that pages navigation bar is working.

Should I include any permission to make navigation work?

Answer (score 0):

please check classes applied to navigation if it missed.

And below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```